# Extending Peano arithmetic with $\Pi_1^0$ sentences

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

My knowledge of mathematical logic is rather poor, so this question might be incoherent. But I was wondering about this.

My understanding is that the natural numbers $\mathbb N$ are thought of as a 'minimal' model of the Peano axioms $PA$. In particular this means that when a $\Pi_1^0$ statement is consistent with $PA$, it is regarded as true in $\mathbb N$.

Let $A = PA$ + (every $\Pi_1^0$ statement which is consistent with $PA$). Assuming that $PA$ is consistent, is $A$ consistent as well? Furthermore, what is the strength of $A$? Is it complete? If not, what kinds of statements are independent of $A$?

Comment: What is a "$\Pi_1^0$ statement?" Could you give some examples?

Comment: @DanChristensen This is a standard term for a particular syntactic class - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for the link.

Comment: Are you proposing additional axiom(s) for the natural numbers? If so, it seems unlikely to me that any of Peano’s 5 axioms can be wrong. It also seems unlikely that you could add some independent axiom(s) that would give a fuller picture of the natural numbers since all Peano-like structures (those that satisfy Peano’s 5 Axioms) are essentially identical, i.e. isomorphic. What possibilities have I overlooked?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, thanks for your comment. I would accept that as an answer.

Comment: @DanChristensen I don't agree that all models of Peano arithmetic are isomorphic. For example, some of them are uncountable. see, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic

Comment: @DanChristensen The OP is talking about first-order Peano arithmetic; the categoricity result you mention is for *second-order* PA.

Comment: @namsos OK, I've turned it into an answer.

Comment: So, you would no longer be talking about the natural numbers, but some other infinite set? Would induction necessarily hold on such sets.

Comment: @Dan They’re models of first-order PA, so they satisfy induction for first-order properties.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Can you prove that no number is its own successor in first-order PA?

Comment: @Dan Yes, any common-sense thing that can be stated in a first order way can be proved there (and plenty of non-obvious things too).

Comment: I found this at Wikipedia: "Although the usual natural numbers satisfy the axioms of PA, there are other models as well (called "non-standard models"); the compactness theorem implies that the existence of nonstandard elements cannot be excluded in first-order logic. [...] The original (second-order) Peano axioms, which have ONLY ONE MODEL, up to isomorphism." (my emphasis) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Nonstandard_models This suggests to me that the second-order Peano axioms are somehow more "natural" and more widely applicable than the first-order version.

Comment: @DanChristensen Second-order PA is more powerful than first-order PA, certainly, but that doesn't make first-order PA (or the study of it or its models) uninteresting (and keep in mind that second-order logic is extremely pathological in many ways - "strong" isn't always the same as "nice"!). Regardless, I don't see what this has to do with the question here, which is about first-order PA.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Maybe it's just me, but results like multiple "models of PA" make me wonder if first-order PA fully captures the essence of the natural numbers, interesting though it may be.

Comment: @DanChristensen First-order PA absolutely doesn't fully capture the essence of the natural numbers. Who ever claimed that it did? But again that doesn't in any sense mean that first-order PA is uninteresting or insignificant. And again, this is all irrelevant to *this specific question*, which is clearly about first-order PA. So I don't know what more there is to be gained here.

Comment: @NoahSchweber +1 Re: "First-order PA absolutely doesn't fully capture the essence of the natural numbers." Thanks for clearing that up. Is that a widely held opinion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as we work in an appropriately rich "background theory" *($\mathsf{ZFC}$ is galactically more than enough, while $\mathsf{PA}$ isn't enough since $\mathsf{PA}$ can't tell that $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent in the first place)* it's easy to show that $A$ is both consistent and incomplete. The basic idea is that $A$ must be consistent since it has a model, namely $\mathbb{N}$ itself. Meanwhile, $A$ is incomplete by complexity considerations: the deductive closure of $A$ has Turing degree ${\bf 0''}$, and while there are consistent complete extensions of $\mathsf{PA}$ which are this simple (or [even simpler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_basis_theorem) in fact) true arithmetic $Th(\mathbb{N})$ is not, and so since $A\subseteq Th(\mathbb{N})$ we have that $A$ is not complete.

In general, the (set of Godel numbers corresponding to the) true $\Pi^0_n$ theory of $\mathbb{N}$ is $\Pi^0_n$-complete in the sense of computability theory. So in fact there is already a $\Pi^0_2$ sentence not decided by $A$. With effort (basically the proof of the MRDP theorem), we can make this reasonably concrete: we can find a specific polynomial $p(x,y_1,...,y_n)$ with integer coefficients such that

- for each $n$ the equation $p(n,y_1,...,y_n)=0$ has a solution (and this is provable in, say, $\mathsf{ZFC}$), but
- $A$ can't prove the previous bulletpoint - or put differently, the sentence $\exists x\forall y_1,...,y_n(p(x,y_1,...,y_n)\not=0)$ is consistent with $A$.

Comment: The deductive closure of $A$ looks to me like a $\Sigma^0_2$-complete set, hence not of degree $\mathbf 0'$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Whoops, fixed!